# Compiling my program with OpenSSL as static library on windows fail

Tags: gcc, compilation, openssl

I wrote a program that is using OpenSSL and I'm trying to compile it to executable for inwdows.

The command I'm using to compile is:

```
gcc -g  -Ifolder1/include  -Iopenssl/include -Ifolder2 -c folder1/lib/functions.c  -o folder1/lib/functions.o
gcc -g  -Ifolder1/include  -Iopenssl/include -Ifolder2 -o myprog.exe main.o folder1/lib/myfiles.o folder1/lib/plus.o folder1/lib/functions.o -Lopenssl/windows/static  -lcrypto
```

This works for linux but for windows i get

`c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lcrypto`

Any idea what is the corresponding flag for -lcrypto for linux?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that in path openssl/windows/static i had a library with the suffix *.lib and seems like gcc doesnt recongnize it as a library.

resolved when i change it to *.a suffix